# Query by Variable Not Working in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in a scheduling application that has 4 columns:

- I : Index of the order the job was requested (Job 1 was requested before Job 2...)
- S : The requested Start Time
- F : The requested Finish Time
- C : The required machine Capacity of the job

Here is a sample set in a dataframe I call bldf:

```
| |I|S|F|C|
|--| --: | --: | --: | --: |
|0|1|1.0|1.4|5|
|1|2|1.1|1.5|5|
|2|3|1.2|1.6|3|
|3|4|1.3|1.7|5|
|4|5|1.4|1.5|4|
|5|6|1.5|1.6|12|
|6|7|1.6|2.1|4|
|7|8|1.7|2.2|4|
```

I have a function that looks at how many concurrent jobs will be running with each new request.

```
def ccj(x):
    return len( bldf[ (bldf['I']<=bldf['I'][x]) &
                      (bldf['S']<bldf['F'][x]) & (bldf['F']>bldf['S'][x]) ] )
```

*x is the row indicator*

This works fine as you can see from the new column constructed with ccj as the output:

```
| |I|S|F|C|ccJobs|
|--| --: | --: | --: | --: | --: |
|0|1|1.0|1.4|5|1|
|1|2|1.1|1.5|5|2|
|2|3|1.2|1.6|3|3|
|3|4|1.3|1.7|5|4|
|4|5|1.4|1.5|4|4|
|5|6|1.5|1.6|12|3|
|6|7|1.6|2.1|4|2|
|7|8|1.7|2.2|4|2|
```

But I need to know this by Requested Capacity (or lower). i.e. If a job is requested at C = 3, then any machine with a capacity of 3 or more can do that job.  So, for example, I want a function that allows me to look at each row in sequence and count how many jobs would be concurrently running at Capacity of 4 or lower, 5 or lower...  Here is my function and **it is not working correctly**:

```
def ccjTC(x,TC):
    return len( bldf[ (bldf['I']<=bldf['I'][x]) &
                      (bldf['S']<bldf['F'][x]) & (bldf['F']>bldf['S'][x]) &
                      (TC >= bldf['C'][x]) ] )
```

*TC is the Target Capacity*

The **(TC >= bldf['C'][x])** condition is not working properly.

If I break open the function and look at the filtered dataframe (remove the len()), it shows that the filter is malfunctioning.

Using:

```
def ccjTC(x,TC):
    return ( bldf[ (bldf['I']<=bldf['I'][x]) &
                      (bldf['S']<bldf['F'][x]) & (bldf['F']>bldf['S'][x]) &
                      (TC >= bldf['C'][x]) ] )
```

with ccjTC(3,3) or ccjTC(3,4) I would expect:

```
| |I|S|F|C|
|--| --: | --: | --: | --: |
|2|3|1.2|1.6|3|
```

but I get an empty frame. Only when I increment TC to 5 do I get what I expected.

```
| |I|S|F|C|
|--| --: | --: | --: | --: |
|0|1|1.0|1.4|5|
|1|2|1.1|1.5|5|
|2|3|1.2|1.6|3|
|3|4|1.3|1.7|5|
```

The row 2 has a requested capacity (C) if 3 yet it is not seen until the TC reaches 5.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Paul pointed out my error - I accidentally put the [x] row reference in the capacity comparison.

The code should have been:

```
def ccjTC(x,TC):
    return len( bldf[ (bldf['I']<bldf['I'][x]) &
                      (bldf['S']<bldf['F'][x]) & (bldf['F']>bldf['S'][x]) &
                      (TC >= bldf['C']) ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

what does this line do

```
return ( bldf[ (bldf['I']<=bldf['I'][x]) &
                  (bldf['S']<bldf['F'][x]) & (bldf['F']>bldf['S'][x]) &
                  (TC >= bldf['C'][x]) ] )
```

it returns true or false ?

Comment: Hi Paul - it looks at Row x in the dataframe and then creates a set of prior rows that meet the conditions for concurrence. e.g. where x = row 3, I = 4, S = 1.3, F = 1.7 and C = 5,  it looks at all previous requests where: I <= 4 & S < 1.7 & F > 1.3 & C ... wait. you just pointed out the problem... What is the [x] doing there? OMG a dozen times and I did not see that.  Paul - thanks. it shld hv been:

Comment: @markfitzpatrick np it was nothing xD i was going to suggest using if but u got better ,and yes u should remove [x] at the last part cause u wanna compare the TC in all lines not selected